# Analyzing log file in node.js

Tags: node.js, logging, analyzer

is there any node module that I can use to analyze the log file?  similar to Splunk but free. :)

By the way, I have 5 servers, each put its log into its server.   what is the best wayto combine them all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like Log.io is what you want? http://logio.org/